# Multi Tenancy using Spring + JPA / hibernate through separate schema & single application approach

Tags: hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

I am looking for some help in design/development of multi-tenant architecture with single application + separate schema approach using `Spring + JPA/Hibernate` frameworks.

A brief summary on requirements is listed below:

1. Single instance of application will be connected to a common data base across users, data source is created when application is deployed in server.
2. For each user of application, we want to have a separate schema/database on a common SQL server.
3. When a user logs-in, application should connect to user specific database on the fly.
4. Response to user after DB hit,  should have merged data from both common + user database. I.e. same entities would be there in both databases – user created content in user database & default content
    on common database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having a schema per user will lead to a huge overhead in the database in terms of space. I know you say is a requirement, but getting rid of it will greatly simplify you setup and development.

Comment: space is not an issue but having multiple instances of application. I understand though, that this might not be highly performance based approach. But, we want do a comparative analysis of different approaches. This is one of the poc approach that i am bit stuck with.